# NSEvent from a NSButton

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsmenu

I have a `NSTableView` and each row contains a button. I also have a menu associated with the table.

The issue is : I want to show the menu on click of button. If possible do not show on right click.

The action method is :

```
- (IBAction)showMenu:(NSButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"show menu");
    NSMenu *menu = [self.tableView menu];
    NSEvent *event = [[NSEvent alloc] init];


    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:menu
                   withEvent:event
                     forView:button];

}
```

Here what to do with `event`? If I use `nil` then the menu is showed at bottom left corner, not next to the button.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can get the current event: `[NSApp currentEvent]`. Consider using a `NSPopupButton` in pull-down mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`-[NSMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsmenu/1518212-popupmenupositioningitem?language=objc). This method doesn't take an `NSEvent` argument. Instead, you give it a view and a location in the view's coordinate system, and the menu positions itself (or one of its items) over that location.

But I would suggest you don't use an `NSButton` at all. If you use an [`NSPopUpButton`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspopupbutton?language=objc) instead, it will take care of showing the menu at the correct location on a left-click.

Comment: Thanks Rob, my requirement is to use NSButton (UI) design I cant change. However I have achieve very similar what you mentioned.                            
   `- (IBAction)showMenu:(NSButton *)button {
    NSMenu *menu = self.tableView.menu;
    
    NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(-menu.size.width, 0);

    
    [menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:[menu itemAtIndex:0]
                        atLocation:point
                            inView:button];
    
}`